# ¿Cómo hacer que se coloquen en estilo lista los iconos y elementos al disminuirlas las dimensiones de la pantalla?

Tags: html, responsive

Estoy utilizando iconos con sus títulos en un div desplegándolos uno al lado del otro y arriba un título del contenido. Al querer probar su desempeño responsive el título del contenido se corta a la mitad en dimensiones de móvil y los elementos se sobreponen quedando estéticamente feo.
Me gustaría que fuera responsive y se coloque uno debajo del otro si la pantalla es pequeña. Si es grande tomo tablets o pc que esten uno al lado del otro.

Probe en cambiarle el dysplay pero no conseguí resultados

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que sea responsive y al tener dimensiones de un celular estos elementos estén uno abajo del otro estilo lista?

Estaré atento a sus consejos. Saludos!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #0f1214;
}


/* ------------- SCROLLBAR ------------- */

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 6.5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.main .heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: -1.1%;
}

.main .heading::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.3rem;
}

.main .heading span {
  margin-left: 1.4rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: .5rem 3rem;
  color: #fffeff;
  background: #332c44;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-transform: none;
  position: static;
}

.main .icons-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(4rem, 1fr));
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  background-color: #695c72;
  padding: 3% 7% 3% 9%;
  border-bottom: #b600ce 2px solid;
  border-top: #b600ce 2px solid;
}

.main .icons-container .icons {
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.main .icons-container .icons i {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.main .icons-container .icons h3 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  /* display: inline; */
  padding: auto;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: none;
}

.main .icons-container .icons p {
  margin-left: 0.1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #b1cdff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692);
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- CSS only -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleItemList.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

</head>

<body style="background-color: rgb(65, 71, 75);">


  <section class="main">

    <h3 class="heading"> <span>Contamos con</span> </h3>

    <section class="icons-container">

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="uil uil-book-alt"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Ámplia variedad</h3>
          <p>+7000 Libros para tí</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="uil uil-dice-five"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Juegos didácticos</h3>
          <p>+50 Juegos para tí</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="uil uil-snowflake"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Ambiente climatizado</h3>
          <p>A/AC Frío - Calor</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="icons">
        <i class="uil uil-book-reader"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Los 365 días del año</h3>
          <p>Te esperamos !</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu etiqueta `section`, tienes a tus 4 elementos, que son esos 4 íconos con sus textos debajo:

```
<section class="icons-container">
  <div class="icons">
    <!-- tus iconos y texto -->
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <!-- tus iconos y texto -->
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <!-- tus iconos y texto -->
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
    <!-- tus iconos y texto -->
  </div>
</section>
```

Tu objetivo es hacerlos responsive. Una forma de hacerlo, en este caso, es trabajar con [**rejillas**](https://getbootstrap.esdocu.com/docs/5.1/layout/columns/).

Para hacerlo, es muy sencillo. Las rejillas deben tener una base para que funcionen, y esto sería las filas. Las filas, se le conocen como `row`, y dentro de esto, irían las rejillas.

---

Entonces, vamos por partes, primero agregamos el `row` encerrando a tus 4 elementos:

```
<section class="icons-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="icons">
      <!-- tus iconos y texto -->
    </div>
    <div class="icons">
      <!-- tus iconos y texto -->
    </div>
    <div class="icons">
      <!-- tus iconos y texto -->
    </div>
    <div class="icons">
      <!-- tus iconos y texto -->
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Y ahora, implementemos las rejillas a los 4 elementos, que en este caso, serían:

```
col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12
```

En donde, digo que primero, se toma el tamaño de `3 / 12` hasta superar el ancho del `lg`, es decir, tus 4 elementos ocupan `3` cada uno, estando los 4 elementos en una fila (ya que su máximo es `12`). Luego de superar el ancho del `lg`, continúa con tomar el tamaño de `6 / 12` hasta superar el ancho del `md`, ocupando 2 cards por fila, ya que cada una ocupan `6`, cabiendo 2 en cada fila. Y por último, toma el `col-12`, indicando que cada elemento ocupa el `12` en cada fila, mostrando 1 elemento por fila.

*Los tamaños en `px` puedes verlo en su [**documentación**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#grid-options).*

---

También agregué estas clases:

```
d-flex flex-column align-items-md-start
```

En donde indico que el contenido de tus elementos serán flexibles, estarán en columnas y estarán alineados al inicio hasta superar el ancho del `md`, una vez superar su ancho, el contenido se alinea al centro, dando un mejor resultado en dispositivos pequeños.

---

Código final:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #0f1214;
}


/* ------------- SCROLLBAR ------------- */

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 6.5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.main .heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: -1.1%;
}

.main .heading::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.3rem;
}

.main .heading span {
  margin-left: 1.4rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: .5rem 3rem;
  color: #fffeff;
  background: #332c44;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-transform: none;
  position: static;
}

.main .icons-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(4rem, 1fr));
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  background-color: #695c72;
  padding: 3% 7% 3% 9%;
  border-bottom: #b600ce 2px solid;
  border-top: #b600ce 2px solid;
}

.main .icons-container .icons {
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.main .icons-container .icons i {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.main .icons-container .icons h3 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  /* display: inline; */
  padding: auto;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: none;
}

.main .icons-container .icons p {
  margin-left: 0.1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #b1cdff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692);
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleItemList.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: rgb(65, 71, 75);">
    <section class="main">
      <h3 class="heading"> <span>Contamos con</span> </h3>
      <section class="icons-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="icons col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-md-start">
            <i class="uil uil-book-alt"></i>
            <div class="content">
              <h3>Ámplia variedad</h3>
              <p>+7000 Libros para tí</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="icons col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-md-start">
            <i class="uil uil-dice-five"></i>
            <div class="content">
              <h3>Juegos didácticos</h3>
              <p>+50 Juegos para tí</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="icons col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-md-start">
            <i class="uil uil-snowflake"></i>
            <div class="content">
              <h3>Ambiente climatizado</h3>
              <p>A/AC Frío - Calor</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="icons col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12 d-flex flex-column align-items-md-start">
            <i class="uil uil-book-reader"></i>
            <div class="content">
              <h3>Los 365 días del año</h3>
              <p>Te esperamos !</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Puedes ver mejor los resultados en [**este enlace**](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/PodRwQq).

Answer (score 2):

¿Por qué no usas Bootstrap para hacer responsiva tu web? Es lo más fácil que hay y tienes mucha información y tutoriales en internet.

Mira lo que se logra con solo agregar Bootstrap a tu proyecto y un par de clases.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 550;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #0f1214;
}


/* ------------- SCROLLBAR ------------- */

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 1.5px;
  width: 6.5px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #acacac;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.main .heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: -1.1%;
}

.main .heading::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.3rem;
}

.main .heading span {
  margin-left: 1.4rem;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  padding: .5rem 3rem;
  color: #fffeff;
  background: #332c44;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-transform: none;
  position: static;
}

.main .icons-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(4rem, 1fr));
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  background-color: #695c72;
  padding: 3% 7% 3% 9%;
  border-bottom: #b600ce 2px solid;
  border-top: #b600ce 2px solid;
}

.main .icons-container .icons {
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.main .icons-container .icons i {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.main .icons-container .icons h3 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  color: #d1d1d1;
  /* display: inline; */
  padding: auto;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: none;
}

.main .icons-container .icons p {
  margin-left: 0.1rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #b1cdff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 .5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.692);
  text-transform: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parser</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- ===== Iconscout CSS ===== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleItemList.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
</head>
<body style="background-color: rgb(65, 71, 75);">
    <section class="main">

    <h3 class="heading"> <span>Contamos con</span> </h3>

    <section class="icons-container">
    <!-- Agrego este div row -->
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Defino cuantas de las 12 columnas que crea Bootstrap tendrá cada div en sus tamaños pequeño (sm) y mediano (md) por default tomará la ultima medida (md) -->
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 icons">
        <i class="uil uil-book-alt"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Ámplia variedad</h3>
          <p>+7000 Libros para tí</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 icons">
        <i class="uil uil-dice-five"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Juegos didácticos</h3>
          <p>+50 Juegos para tí</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 icons">
        <i class="uil uil-snowflake"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Ambiente climatizado</h3>
          <p>A/AC Frío - Calor</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 icons">
        <i class="uil uil-book-reader"></i>
        <div class="content">
          <h3>Los 365 días del año</h3>
          <p>Te esperamos !</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End div row -->
    </section>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Básicamente, solo fueron 3 pasos y listo!!!

Comment: Hola, no necesitas escribir en el cuerpo de la respuesta el texto para que se acepte tu respuesta, es muy buena respuesta!

Comment: Ok @Jorgesys, lo tomaré en cuenta...